# string to Enum in c#

Tags: c#, enums

I need to assign a string to a `Enum` value. My scenario and code below

Am accessing a webservice method say `addWhere(int i ,int j,Comparison)`

Where Comparison is of type Enum.

Am fetching value from UI and having it in a string

```
string strComparison= "AND"; or

string strComparison= "OR"
```

i need to set these values to `ENUM`. I tried the below code

```
addWhere(2 ,3,Enum.Parse(typeof(Comparison),strComparison))
```

But didnt worked. What is the way to solve this or any alternate methods ?

Thanks

Comment: `Enum.Parse` is the solution, there is no good alternative. You don't say what goes wrong. See the duplicate or the documentation.

Comment: "didn't work" is never an acceptable problem description. **What** didn't work? What **error** did you get? Please keep in mind to include all **relevant details** in your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your missing the return cast i.e.

```
(Comparison)Enum.Parse(typeof(Comparison), strComparison);
```

[Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/essfb559.aspx) returns an `object` were as your `addWhere` method is expecting a `Comparison` type value.

Answer (score 0):

You must cast the result of `Enum.Parse` to the correct type:

```
addWhere(2, 3, (Comparison)Enum.Parse(typeof(Comparison), strComparison));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
Comparison comparison;
if(Comparison.TryParse(strComparison, out comparison))
{
   // Work with the converted Comparison
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in earlier posts, you might be missing type casting.

```
enum Comparision
{
        AND,
        OR
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Comparision cmp = (Comparision)Enum.Parse(typeof (Comparision), "And", true);
        Console.WriteLine(cmp == Comparision.OR  );
        Console.WriteLine(cmp == Comparision.AND);
    }
}
```